# Optimizing text drawing on screen

Tags: performance, strings, objective-c, graphics

I'm looking to speed up this method. Ideally, I would like to cut the time in 1/2 or more. At the moment I have to draw the screen line-by-line as the font is 16 pixels high, but it is being drawn with an extra blank pixel on the bottom. If I could figure out how to set the line-height to 16 pixels I would imagine that drawing 1 string over 24 strings would help speed it up. Baring that what else can I do to increase the speed?

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSGraphicsContext *nsGraphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef) [nsGraphicsContext graphicsPort];

    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, false);


    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for (int y=24; y >= 0; y--) {
        [[string mutableString] setString:@""];;
        for (int x=0; x < 80; x++) {
            AnsiScreenChar *c = [self.screen objectAtIndex:(y*80)+x];
            [self.fontAttributes setValue:c.fgColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
            [self.fontAttributes setValue:c.bgColor forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];

            NSAttributedString *subString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:c.data
                                                                            attributes:self.fontAttributes];
            [string appendAttributedString:subString];
        }
        [string drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, self.frame.size.height - ((y+1)*16))];
    }
}
```

**Profile**

> ```
> Running     Time  Self        Symbol Name
> 3276.0ms    9.5%  3276.0      -[AnsiView drawRect:]
> 1726.0ms    5.0%  1726.0      -[NSLayoutManager(NSTextViewSupport) showCGGlyphs:positions:count:font:matrix:attributes:inContext:]
> 1540.0ms    4.4%  1540.0      -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]
> 1467.0ms    4.2%  1467.0      -[NSObject dealloc]
> 1118.0ms    3.2%  1118.0      -[NSView _drawRect:clip:]
> 1108.0ms    3.2%  1108.0      -[NSConcreteHashTable getItem:]
> 1106.0ms    3.2%  1106.0      -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:atPoint:parameters:]
> 901.0ms     2.6%  901.0       -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _insertionPointHelperForGlyphAtIndex:]
> 779.0ms     2.2%  779.0       -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:]
> 704.0ms     2.0%  704.0       -[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]
> 693.0ms     2.0%  693.0       -[NSATSGlyphStorage createCTTypesetter]
> 619.0ms     1.8%  619.0       -[NSAttributeDictionary objectForKey:]
> 599.0ms     1.7%  599.0       -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _rectArrayForRange:withinSelectionRange:rangeIsCharRange:singleRectOnly:fullLineRectsOnly:inTextContainer:rectCount:rangeWithinContainer:glyphsDrawOutsideLines:]
> 558.0ms     1.6%  558.0       -[NSLayoutManager locationForGlyphAtIndex:]
> 537.0ms     1.5%  537.0       +[NSObject allocWithZone:]
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to avoid as much work inside `drawRect:` as possible. Instead of recalculating the attributed string for each line here do it whenever `self.screen` changes. That way it's done once instead of every time the some portion of the view is redrawn (which will happen a lot).

Maybe keep a `self.lines` array with the attributed string for each line in it. Or maybe it's a dictionary with the key being the line number and you just keep adding lines and `drawRect` just draws the last `displayHeight` lines.

Basically do everything you can to remove unnecessary work from `drawRect`.

Answer (score 1):

The code has been changed according to the review and currently looks as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSGraphicsContext *nsGraphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef) [nsGraphicsContext graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(context, false);    

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for (int y=24; y >= 0; y--) {
        [[string mutableString] setString:@""];;
        for (int x=0; x < 80; x++) {
            AnsiScreenChar *c = [self.screen objectAtIndex:(y*80)+x];
            [string appendAttributedString:c.data];
        }
        [string drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, self.frame.size.height - ((y+1)*16))];
    }
}
```

As visible, the inner for-loop has been significantly simplified by removing the fontAttributes changes. Also the superfluous substring-creation has been removed.

This leads to a significantly improved profile, as seen below

```
Running    Time    Self     Symbol Name
590.0ms    6.5%    590.0        -[AnsiView drawRect:]
561.0ms    6.2%    561.0        -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _insertionPointHelperForGlyphAtIndex:]
417.0ms    4.6%    417.0        -[NSObject retain]
366.0ms    4.0%    366.0        -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:atPoint:parameters:]
320.0ms    3.5%    0.0      -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
318.0ms    3.5%    318.0        -[NSLayoutManager(NSTextViewSupport) showCGGlyphs:positions:count:font:matrix:attributes:inContext:]
240.0ms    2.6%    240.0        -[NSLayoutManager glyphRangeForCharacterRange:actualCharacterRange:]
236.0ms    2.6%    236.0        -[NSLayoutManager locationForGlyphAtIndex:]
230.0ms    2.5%    230.0        -[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]
212.0ms    2.3%    0.0      -[NSView _drawRect:clip:]
189.0ms    2.0%    189.0        -[NSATSGlyphStorage createCTTypesetter]
188.0ms    2.0%    188.0        -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _rectArrayForRange:withinSelectionRange:rangeIsCharRange:singleRectOnly:fullLineRectsOnly:inTextContainer:rectCount:rangeWithinContainer:glyphsDrawOutsideLines:]
183.0ms    2.0%    183.0        -[NSBigMutableString getCharacters:range:]
169.0ms    1.8%    0.0      -[NSFrameView drawWindowBackgroundRect:]
144.0ms    1.5%    144.0        -[NSConcreteGlyphGenerator generateGlyphsForGlyphStorage:desiredNumberOfCharacters:glyphIndex:characterIndex:]
```